# Tuple unpacking/For loop

Tags: python

I am trying to do a simple tuple unpacking with following -

```
T1=[(1,3,6),(9,4,6),(7,11,8)]

for (t1,t2) in T1 :

          print(t1)
```

I am getting following error -

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[30], line 1
----> 1 for (tup1,tup2) in T1:
      2     print(tup1)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Why it is so?

Comment: You can't unpack three elements into two variables.

Comment: Acutally you sort of can (partial unpacking), by replacing `(t1, t2)` with `(t1, *t2)`

Comment: `T1` contains 3 elements, each consisting in itself of 3 elements, so you should change your for loop to `for (t1,t2,t3) in T1:`

Answer (score 2):

Tuples in T1 list have 3 values, so you need 3 variables to unpack.

```
T1=[(1,3,6),(9,4,6),(7,11,8)]

for (t1,t2,t3) in T1 :
    print(t1,t2,t3)
```

> output

```
1 3 6
9 4 6
7 11 8
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't unpack a N-tuple into anything other than N discrete variables **unless** a target variable name is prefixed with asterisk in which case that variable will become a list.

Consider this:

```
t = 1, 2, 3 # 3-tuple
    
a, b, c = t # 1-to-1 unpacking
print(a, b, c)

a, *b = t
print(a, b)

*a, b = t
print(a, b)
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3
1 [2, 3]
[1, 2] 3
```

In the original question it seems that it's only the first item in the tuple that's required. Therefore:

```
T1 = [(1,3,6), (9,4,6), (7,11,8)]

for t1, *_ in T1:
    print(t1)
```

**Output:**

```
1
9
7
```

**Note:**

By using a starred expression we can handle any N-tuple where N > 0.
There can be at most one starred expression on the left of the assignment operator